# How to retrieve variadic template parameters without auxillary function template?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Suppose I have

```cpp
template<int ...>
struct Ints { };

class MyClass
{
public:
    Ints<1, 2, 3> get() { return Ints<1, 2, 3>(); }
};
```

What I want to do is simple.

```cpp
template <class T>
vector<int> MyFunc1(T& x)
{
    Ints<S...> result = x.get();
    vector<int> t = { S... };
    return t;
}
```

Somewhat like this. (Here `MyClass` can be one example of `T`.) Apparently, for compiler `S...` seems to invalid.

```cpp
template <class T, int... S>
vector<int> MyFunc2(T& x)
{
    Ints<S...> result = x.get();
    vector<int> t = { S... };
    return t;
}
```

This doesn't work either. I think from `get()` the `S...` becomes specific and automatically deducible, but compiler doesn't recognize it. (I'm not sure but C++ doesn't deduce template parameters looking inside the function, but only arguments and return type)

The only way I've found is to use another function that finds out what `int...` was.

```cpp
template <int ...S>
vector<int> temp(Ints<S...> not_used)
{
    return { S... };
}

template <class T>
vector<int> MyFunc3(T& x)
{
    auto result = x.get();
    return temp(result);
}
```

It works well, but requires another extra helper function that does nothing but just provides syntactically clear way to match the `S...` using templates.

I really want to do this just in **single function**. Do I really have to define auxiliary function whenever I want to retrieve parameter packs, in every time?

Edit : `Ints` and `MyFunc` are just toy example. I want to know general method  to retrieve template parameters!

Comment: "Do I really have to define auxiliary function..." Why is it a problem? What do you want to do with the template parameters? Do you want to do the same with them, or different? If the same, maybe you can have a "more templated" `temp`, so there would be only one auxiliary function needed. If different, then it shouldn't be a real problem that you'll need more `temp` template functions.

Comment: @geza My question is why c++ doesn't provide convenient way of pattern matching, but only making possible in function arguments. ``temp`` is perfectly fine, but the problem is that  ``temp`` is doing nothing but just providing another templates to match ``int...``. (making into vector is just a example of particular job. It may be passed by ``std::function`` or whatever, so doesn't even matter)

Comment: I think that you can use a lamba for this purpose as well. Development of C++ can be influenced by proposals, if you have a great idea, just make one, and submit it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## What would the ideal interface look like?

If given a variable of type `Ints<S...>`, we'd ideally be able to use `S...` with as little modification as possible.

In this case, we can design an interface which allows us to use the parameter pack as an input to a variadic function or lambda, even going so far as to reuse the values as template parameters.

## Proposed interface [Dynamic case / ints passed as values]

Both the static case and the dynamic case have similar interfaces, however the dynamic case is slightly cleaner, and makes for a better introduction. Given the variable and a function, we apply the function with the parameter pack contained in the definition of the variable.

```
Ints<1, 2, 3> ints;

// Get a vector from ints
// vec = {1, 2, 3}
auto vec = ints | [](auto... S) { return std::vector {S...}; };

// Get an array from ints
// arr = {1, 2, 3}
auto arr = ints | [](auto... S) { return std::array {S...}; }; 

// Get a tuple from ints
// tup = {1, 2, 3}
auto tup = ints | [](auto... S) { return std::make_tuple(S...); };

// Get sum of ints using a fold expression
auto sum = ints | [](auto... S) { return (S + ...); };
```

It's a simple, unified syntax which allows us to take `S` and use it as a parameter pack.

### Writing this interface

This part is pretty straight-forward too. We take a variable of type `Ints<S...>`, and a function, and apply the function with `S...`.

```
template<int... S, class Func>
auto operator|(Ints<S...>, Func&& f) {
    return f(S...); 
}
```

## Proposed interface [Static case / ints usable as template parameters]

As stated before, the static case has a similar interface to the dynamic case, and it won't be too much of a stretch conceptually. From a user standpoint, the only difference is that instead of using `S...` as the parameter pack, we`ll use`S.value...` as the pack.

For each value, we want to encapsulate it in a corresponding type templated on the value. This allows us to access it in a constexpr context.

```
template<int Value>
struct ConstInt {
    constexpr static int value = Value;
};
```

To differentiate it from the dynamic case, I'm going to overload `/` instead of `|`. Otherwise, they behave similarly. The implementation is pretty much the same as the dynamic case, except that the values are wrapped in the `ConstInt` class, and each will have it's own type.

```
template<int... S, class F>
auto operator/(Ints<S...>, F&& func) {
    return func(ConstInt<S>()...); 
}
```

### Using this interface statically

C++ allows us to access static members of a class using the same syntax as non-static members, without losing `constexpr` status.

Let's say I have some `ConstInt` with a value of 10. I can directly use `I.value` as a template parameter, or I can use `decltype(I)::value`:

```
// This is what'll be passed in as a parameter
ConstInt<10> I;

std::array<int, I.value> arr1;
std::array<int, decltype(I)::value> arr2; 
// Both have length 10
```

Expanding a parameter pack is therefore extraordinarily straight-forward, and it ends up being almost identical to the dynamic case, the only difference being the `.value` appended to `S`. Shown below are the examples from the dynamic case, this time using the static case syntax:

```
Ints<1, 2, 3> ints;

// Get a vector from ints
auto vec = ints | [](auto... S) { return std::vector {S.value...}; };

// Get an array from ints
// arr = {1, 2, 3}
auto arr = ints | [](auto... S) { return std::array {S.value...}; }; 

// Get a tuple from ints
auto tup = ints | [](auto... S) { return std::make_tuple(S.value...); };

// Get sum of ints using a fold expression
auto sum = ints | [](auto... S) { return (S.value + ...); };
```

So what's new? **Because `value` is constexpr, `S.value` can be used trivially as a template parameter.** In this example, we use `S.value` to index into a tuple using `std::get`:

```
auto tupA = std::make_tuple(10.0, "Hello", 3); 

auto indicies = Ints<2, 0, 1>{};

// tupB = {3, 10.0, "Hello"}
auto tupB = indicies / [&](auto... S) { 
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<S.value>(tupA)...);
};
```

And in this example, we square every element in a sequence, and return a new sequence:

```
auto ints = Ints<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(); 

// ints_squared = Ints<0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25>(); 
auto ints_squared = ints / [](auto... S) {
    return Ints<(S.value * S.value)...>(); 
};
```

## Alternative solution that avoids operator overloading

If you want to avoid operator overloading, we can take some inspiration from functional programming and handle things with an `unpack` function, written like so:

```
template<int... vals>
auto unpack(Ints<vals...>) {
    return [](auto&& f) { return f(vals...); }; 
}

// Static case
template<int... vals>
auto unpack_static(Ints<vals...>) {
    return [](auto&& f) { return f(ConstInt<vals>()...); }; 
}
```

**So what is `unpack`?** This function takes a bunch of values, and it returns a function which takes another function and applies the function with the vals as inputs.

The `unpack` function allows us to apply those values to a different function, as parameters.

We can assign the result to a variable called `apply_ints`, and then we can use `apply_ints` to handle all the specific use-cases:

```
Ints<1, 2, 3> ints; //this variable has our ints

auto apply_ints = unpack(ints); // We use this function to unpack them
```

We can re-write the examples from before, this time using `apply_ints`:

```
// Get a vector from ints
// vec = {1, 2, 3}
auto vec = apply_ints([](auto... S) { return std::vector {S...}; });

// Get an array from ints
// arr = {1, 2, 3}
auto arr = apply_ints([](auto... S) { return std::array {S...}; }); 

// Get a tuple from ints
// tup = {1, 2, 3}
auto tup = apply_ints([](auto... S) { return std::make_tuple(S...); });

// Get sum of ints using a fold expression
auto sum = apply_ints([](auto... S) { return (S + ...); });
```

## Appendix

This appendix gives a brief overview showing how to use this syntax more generally (such as when working with multiple separate parameter packs).

### Bonus example: pairing up values from two separate packs

To give you a better idea of the flexibility of this interface, here's an example where we use it to pair up values from two separate packs.

```
Ints<1, 2, 3> intsA;
Ints<10, 20, 30> intsB;

// pairs = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}}
auto pairs = intsA | [&](auto... S1) {
    return intsB | [&](auto... S2) {
        return std::vector{ std::pair{S1, S2}... }; 
    };
};
```

**NB:** MSVC and GCC both compile this example without issues, however clang chokes up on it. I assume MSVC and GCC are correct, but I don't know for sure.

### Bonus example: Getting a 2-dimensional times table

This example is a little more complicated, but we can also create 2-dimensional arrays of values that draw from all combinations of values from separate packs.

In this case, I use it to create a times table.

```
Ints<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9> digits;

auto multiply = [](auto mul, auto... vals) {
    return std::vector{(mul * vals)...}; 
};

auto times_table = digits | [&](auto... S1) {
    return digits | [&](auto... S2) {
        return std::vector{ multiply(S1, S2...)... };
    };
};
```

Comment: This would have been a really great answer in some other context - but the OP is specificly trying to avoid auxilery functions... so it's simply too complicated a solution for what is needed.

Comment: @darune: there is only one aux function, which is generic enough to be not a problem (i.e., there is no need to have one additional aux function for each use)

Comment: This really can be made into an immediately invoked lambda expression if OP wants to use it only in one place.

Comment: IMO it's still shooting (way) above the target. you have just created a generalized function instead - and requires now a more convoluted way to create+apply the lambda function. While this can be great, IMO it is shooting above the target and not what OP is asking for !

Comment: I added an alternative solution that doesn't involve the creation of an `apply_ints` helper function, and looks more elegant

Comment: @YSC: That lambda can only be done in C++20 though (templated lambda).

Comment: Your answer is very great. I really appreciate it. But, the problem is ``auto...S`` is function parameter, not template parameter. That means ``S...`` is not a compile-time expression, (unlikely to ``S...`` in ``temp``) so this beautiful interface helps only in case where I want to construct some dynamic expression. (like your example, making vector, calling another function...). What if I want to make tuple from extracting indices specified in ``Ints``? ``make_tuple(get<S>(mytuple)...)`` works well in ``temp`` but not here.

Comment: If you want to do type transformations (like automatically converting Ints<1, 2, 3> to std::index_sequence<1, 2, 3> or something) I could provide a way to do that automatically. C++20 also introduces templated lambdas, which achieve what you want (you can just write the stuff inline), but I can't think of a general way to do what you want in C++17 without writing a separate, templated function

Comment: @i.stav YOOOO!!!!! I FOUND A GENERAL WAY TO DO IT IN THE STATIC CASE!!! WE SOLVED YOUR PROBLEM :D :D :D

Comment: @J. Antonio Perez Wow. This is a hidden usage of ``auto...``. I've never thought that would work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

In C++2a, you might use templated lambda to define your helper inside your function, something like:

```
auto v = []<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){return std::vector{Is...};}(seq);
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ New in C++2a
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b27eb17bcf2d4d0)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be very simple way of doing inside-function pattern matching

Comment: It mostly equivalent to functor with `template <std::size_t...Is> auto operator()(std::index_sequence<Is...>) const;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use/create a helper template, you need *some other way* to provide the values.

The most simple, canonical and general way I can think of, is to put them in that same class scope, so that your `Ints` struct becomes:

```
template<int ...ints>
struct Ints {
  constexpr static std::initializer_list<int> vals = {ints...};
};
```

Since it is `constexpr` it should be evaluated at compile time and not incur a runtime cost.
Now you will be able do something like:

```
return std::vector<int>(ints.vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding functions to the `struct Int` to get different representations

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template<int ...values>
struct Ints {
    auto getAsVector() const {
        return std::vector<int>({ values... });
    }

    constexpr auto getAsArray() const {
        return std::array<int, sizeof...(values)>({ values... });
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    Ints<1, 2, 3> get() { return Ints<1, 2, 3>(); }
};

int main() {
    MyClass a;
    auto array = a.get().getAsVector();
    return array.size();

}
```

Comment: Nope. Making into vector is just for explain. Ints and MyFunc is toy example. I don't even want to do that. I'm asking general solution

Comment: @i.stav There is no truly general solution. You have to use helper functions/classes, but you can try to make those helpers as general as possible (e.g. you could pass container as `template <typename> typename>` template parameter to them).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok thanks, but what I really wonder is like this : why doesn't c++ provide simple and clear way like ``MyFunc2``? Why isn't pattern matching available inside the function?